# How to access calling function from called function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to know calling return parent function in child function.

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res, next) {
        var result = child('test_Val', next);

        return res.send(200);
    }); 

function child(arg1, next) {
   if (condition) {
      //I want to call return parent function with next() here.
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You don't mean 'parent' and 'child' function, you mean 'calling' and 'called' function. No, you can't see the calling function from the called function. If you want to do that, it means something is wrong with your logic. What do you mean by "call return parent function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preface, you *really* shouldn't do this.  Your question almost certainly means that you're designing something wrong, and doing this will disable large swathes of optimizations in v8.

But you can do it.

From inside a function, the magic variable `arguments` is available.  This is an array-like that contains all of the arguments to that function.  Additionally, it has some interesting properties - one of which is `callee`.  This is a reference to the function you're currently in.  It also has a few interesting properties.  One is `arguments`, which points back to the original `arguments` object.  The one we're looking for is `caller`.

So, from inside a function, `arguments.callee.caller` is a reference to the calling function.

Again, please don't do this.  You should ask another question with more context so that someone can help you solve the real problem here.

Comment: (With the caveat that `callee` isn't allowed in strict mode.)